# ESRI - Return Attributes when Feature Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, dojo, esri, arcgis-js-api

I would like to be able to click on an individual feature point and have it return a specific value of a specific attribute associated with the point clicked. I do not need an info template as to display this value on the map but rather need the value to make a call to a separate service. Is the attributes and their values stored in the layer? Where?

```
        // onclick handler for meters. 
        dojo.connect(Lyr, "onClick", function (evt) {

            console.log(evt.???);

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [3.x version of the JavaScript API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/), and your layer type is FeatureLayer, here is how you would get that info:

```
on(lyr, 'click', function(evt) {
    alert('objectid is: ' + evt.graphic.attributes.objectid + '. echelon is ' + evt.graphic.attributes.echelon);
});
```

The documentation is [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#event-click), and a sample app is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/boeun5x3/2/). Hope this helps!